# Excel Sum Top N Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have the following table:

[image]

And I want to sum the top N values. N being the number in cell A1, which can be any number, like 2 or 7.

I know how to do with a fixed number, like:

```
=SUM(LARGE(B1:B9;{1;2;3;4}))
```

But what if the number of companies I want to sum changes?

Thanks!

Comment: `=SUM(LARGE(B1:B9;ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,$A$1))` or if you have Office 365 you could use SEQUENCE

Comment: What happens when there is a tie with the N th value?  ie you want top 3  but the values are 30, 20, 10,10,10,10, 5

Comment: @ForwardEd In your example, the LARGE() function returns 30, 20, 10 and SUM() equals 60.  Relative functions like LARGE, SMALL, MIN, MAX, etc. are not tripped up by ties.

Comment: @MaxR The question more should ties be counted or not counted in the sum.  IE should the answer be 90 or 60.  Its kind of like the olympic scoring system.  if two teams tie for bronze, they both get bronze.  So in an olypic event where three sets of medals are supposed to be handed out, four are actually handed out.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways. Try any of the following

```
=SUM(LARGE(B2:B9,SEQUENCE(5)))
=SUM(INDEX(SORT(B2:B9,1,-1),SEQUENCE(5)))
=SUM(FILTER(B2:B9,B2:B9>=LARGE(B2:B9,5)))
```

[image]

Comment: `=SUM(TAKE(SORT(B2:B9,1,-1),5))`

Comment: @P.b Thanks. If we find, then will get few more.

Comment: @P.b `=SUM(TAKE(SORT(B2:B9),-5))` =)

Comment: @JvdV Short and nice